# Powershell Problemas com o carácter [

Tags: powershell

Boa tarde, estou utilizando o seguinte script em *powershell* para copiar arquivos de uma pasta para a outra:

```
Function CopyFiles
{
    Param ($folderSource, $folderDestiny)
    
    $allFilesSource = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderSource
    $allFilesDestiny = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderDestiny

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $allFilesSource.Count; $i++) 
    {
        $curFileName = $allFilesSource[$i].Name
        $fileExist = "$folderDestiny\$curFileName"
        
        for ($j = 0; $j -lt $allFilesDestiny.Count; $j++)
        {               
            if (-not(Test-Path -path $fileExist))
            {                
                Copy-Item $allFilesSource[$i].FullName $folderDestiny
            }            
        }        
    }
}

CopyFiles 'c:\PastaOrigem' 'D:\PastaDestino'
```

O problema é que na pasta *PastaOrigem* existe arquivos com o carácter "[" e esse arquivos o `script` não copia, alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

A solução é utilizar o parâmetro `-LiteralPath` no lugar de `-Path`.

A documentação pode ser encontrada [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7).

> -LiteralPath
>
> Specifies a path to one or more locations. The value of LiteralPath is
> used exactly as it's typed. No characters are interpreted as
> wildcards. If the path includes escape characters, enclose it in
> single quotation marks. Single quotation marks tell PowerShell not to
> interpret any characters as escape sequences.

Fiz algumas alterações na sua função para que ela funcione corretamente.

```
Function CopyFiles
{
    Param ($folderSource, $folderDestiny)
    
    Get-ChildItem -Path $folderSource | % {
        
        $curFileName = $_.Name
        $curFullFileName = $_.FullName

        Get-Item -Path $folderDestiny | Where { -not (Test-Path -LiteralPath "$_\$curFileName") } | % {
            Copy-Item -LiteralPath $curFullFileName "$_.\$curFileName"
        }
    }
}

CopyFiles 'c:\PastaOrigem' 'D:\PastaDestino'
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo